# What is the process for getting a non-EU PhD "validated" in Germany so I can continue working as university associated faculty?

Tags: phd, germany, eu

I am a medical doctor in Bosnia and Herzegovina (which is not in the EU). I also hold a PhD title and am an associated professor on the medical faculty. I am moving to Germany (Oberbayern). I have already done all the necessary additional work so that I can continue practicing medicine in Germany.

I also want to continue my career in research and possibly work at a German university. I have several publications. For this, I assume my PhD will have to be "recognized" by some German institution. How does this work? Who do I contact?

Comment: Like many things in Germany, recognition procedures vary from one Bundesland to the next. For example, according to [this possibly outdated document](https://www.hamburg.de/contentblob/164670/5bf55277bb6d76557d1d5b95dfea7bac/data/auslaendische-hochschulgrade.pdf), in Hamburg you would contact the Behörde für Wissenschaft,  Forschung und Gleichstellung (something like "Board of Science, Research, and Equality"). In other parts of Germany, there's probably a local body with some other name.

Comment: Your career is relevant - if you want to take work that legally requires certain qualifications (examples might be in architecture, engineering, teaching, among other things), then going through the recognition procedure (or at least verifying that it's not necessary in your case) will be important. If your job doesn't have those legal requirements, it's essentially up to potential employers to decide whether they accept the qualifications or not.

Answer (score -2):

PhD is often less problematic than MSc. It helps if your country is in the EU, but expect some bureaucracy. Contact the Bavarian ministry of education.